# Maximum/Last element of POSIXct column in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, max, posixct

I have a data.table with one column of POSIXcts.

```
dt <- data.table(DateTime=seq(from=as.POSIXct("2017-02-01 00:00", tz="Europe/Berlin"), by=3600, length.out = 10), Value=1:10)
```

I thought I can use max(), but that does not work.

```
maxDateTime <- max(dt[, "DateTime"])
```

And also last() from 'data.table' package is not doing it:

```
maxDateTime <- last(dt[, "DateTime"])
```

Only tail() is going in the right direction

```
maxDateTime <- tail(dt[, "DateTime"],1)
```

but returns a data.table, where I only would like to have a single value.

It is a rather simple problem, but I am stuck with it for a while now, so I hope for the right hint here. Thanks!

Comment: Ditch the quotes and then all your attempts will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to use `[[` to extract a single column

```
max(dt[["DateTime"]])
```

For multiple columns, the syntax is

```
dt[, c("DateTime", "Value"), with = FALSE]
```

Or another option is `.`

```
dt[, .(DateTime, Value)]
```

Comment: Thank you. The first option is totally doing it!

Comment: or `max(df$DateTime)`